# Handling checkbox values being modified from 'true'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

During a scan of an application at work, it became clear that modifying an input's value, then posting it potentially causes rendering issues if you try to pass that model back to the view. 
For example, with the model:

```
public class Survey
{
    public bool LikesCandy { get; set; }
}
```

The actions:

```
public ActionResult Survey()
{
    return View(new Survey());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Survey(Survey model)
{
    //do something worthwhile with the model, like validation, etc. etc.

    //even setting the model's boolean doesn't help the rendering.
    model.LikesCandy = true;

    //then return to the page
    return View(model);
}
```

And a basic razor view:

```
@model BoolTest.Models.Survey

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(i => i.LikesCandy)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

The form gets rendered something like:

```
<form action="/Home/Survey" method="post">
    <input checked="checked" id="LikesCandy" name="LikesCandy" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="LikesCandy" type="hidden" value="false">    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Posting that works fine.

However, if someone changes the input value like so:

```
<form action="/Home/Survey" method="post">
    <input checked="checked" id="LikesCandy" name="LikesCandy" type="checkbox" value="foobar">
    <input name="LikesCandy" type="hidden" value="false">    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The model looks reasonable on the server-side (it defaults `LikesCandy` to false), but the view rendering will always fail with `String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.`.

Can someone explain why this is so? And is there some idiomatic way to fix/handle this? I can do something like use reflection to compare the model's property's types to the request form and give the user some "stop that!" message, or write my own html tags and manually bind the model to those, but neither seem very clean/extensible/correct.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue here. This is only a problem if the user deliberately edits the HTML and changes a value, which if they're doing that, no counter-measures you could possibly provide client-side would be effective, since they could just be disabled as well. And, if a user does do this, it's *perfectly* reasonable to spit back a 500.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I tend to agree that a 500 is probably a reasonable response, especially since this should only happen when someone's messing with the form. I was looking for a way to handle this server-side (without just letting the render fail) because generally our development team treats any 500 error as more of a code-quality issue with not handling some edge case. Thanks for the response though, it's definitely a reasonable suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, it's typical to equate 500 with code quality, because, well, 9 times out of 10, it *is*. However, 500 merely means that the server could not return a response, and sometimes, that's how it should be. This is more an issue of properly evaluating the *cause* of a 500, instead of just assuming someone on the team screwed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As stated in the comments, the model binder is expecting a true or a false.  If you submit something else for that field then a 500 error is the expected response.  Also, if you change the value of the model during the post processing and then redisplay the view then you're not going to see the model change made in the controller reflected in the POST response.  See here:

http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/modelstate-clear-is-required-to-display-back-your-model-object

```
public ActionResult Survey()
{
    return View(new Survey());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Survey(Survey model)
{
    //do something worthwhile with the model, like validation, etc. etc.

    //even setting the model's boolean doesn't help the rendering.
    model.LikesCandy = true;

    //clear model state so that the change on the line above is applied
    ModelState.Clear();

    //then return to the page
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: `String was not recognized as a valid Boolean` sounds like a runtime error, to me, not a validation error, in which case this won't fix anything. However, you are correct that the problem is in the modelbinder, but the solution would have to be creating a custom modelbinder to check for this edge case. That's a lot of work for very little reward, though. Like I said in my comment, just return the 500 and be done.

Comment: Right.  Sorry to admit that I didn't read the whole question the first time around (yikes!).  I edited the response to address both the actual question and what I assumed the question was about.